# Breaking One Time Pad with CCA

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I was taught that:

```
although OTP is CPA secure, it is not the case with CCA.
```

I'm trying to figure how to break OTP with CCA by showing how it fails the IND test.

Note: [Saw this answer, but didn't manage to extract a proper proof](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25683/is-one-time-pad-considered-chosen-plaintext-attack-secure/25686?noredirect=1#comment79482_25686).

- So according to the test, the attacker chooses two messages m1, m2 of the same length, and sends them for the tester.
- In the next stage, the tester privately creates an encryption key, randomly chooses which message to encrypt, and returns c* which is the chosen message encrypted.
- Now, the attacker is able to use his chosen-ciphertext capability and decrypt any message he wants to (maybe messages - I'm not sure about this detail), as long as his chosen message is not c*, in order to guess which message was encrypted (m1 or m2).

What I already thought of:

Maybe we could split c* apart, decrypt both parts and concatenate.
Or we could also add a 0 in the end of c* and then decrypt the result.

But both methods wouldn't work since the key is in the length of the original message - so it cannot decrypt messages in other lengths.

So I add a condition of which the attacker can only decrypt messages in the same length of c* (and the original messages, obviously).

So now I thought about decrypting c* but replacing the last bit to 0.

Assume c* length is n, so the in the encrypted result, denoted as r*, I know the first n-1 bits are of m1 or m2, except for the last one, so I'd distinguish between the messages by comparing the n-1 bits with each of them (of course that'd require sending different messages for the test).

I feel like I'm missing something but can't figure out what exactly.

Does anyone have better example of breaking OTP with CCA, or can justify my answer?

P.S. Just a clarification: I assume of course that key is replaced in each encryption (but it doesn't matter here because decryption is done with the same key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually fairly straight-forward; the attacker knows $m_0$, $m_1$, and the challenge ciphertext $c = m_r \oplus s$, for an unknown bit $r$ and an unknown string $s$; his job is to recover $r$.

One thing he can try is selecting an arbitrary ciphertext $c'$ (which needs to be distinct from the challenge ciphertext, but can be anything else of the same length), and ask for it to be decrypted.  The decryption is $m' = c' \oplus s$; he can then recover $m_r = c' \oplus m' \oplus c$; he can then compare $m_r$ to $m_0$ and $m_1$ to deduce $r$.

Comment: Ah I don't belive it was that easy - I just went too far in other direction... thanks alot!