# Is the One-Time-Pad IND-CCA2 Secure?

Tags: one-time-pad, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I know that the OTP is considered to have perfect secrecy, but I haven't seen anything about its security against [chosen ciphertext attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen_ciphertext_attack/adaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack_(IND-CCA1,_IND-CCA2)), and I was wondering about its secrecy in this regard. My intuition is that it shouldn't be since I'd imagine it has the same issues as CTR$ against a chosen ciphertext attack, but I am not certain.

Comment: OTP cannot be IND-CCA secure because it is not even IND-CPA secure.

Comment: Oh I see, from here -- it doesn't fit the definition of IND-CPA well https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25683/is-one-time-pad-considered-chosen-plaintext-attack-secure

Comment: Wow, the answers to that question are crazy to me. I wasn't aware there was such a variety of interpretations of a statement that is (to me) 100% unambiguous.

Comment: No! See [Easy explanation of "IND-" security notions?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/18298). For beyond Ind-CPA we need integrity.